# When doing socket programming, what is the correct way to look up a domain name and then connect to it?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, gethostbyname

I've programmed networked applications, but primarily in Python.

I'm writing a C++ application and I'm a little fuzzy on exactly what the syntax should be to look up a domain name and connect to it's IP address.

Specifically, I'm not sure how to go form the result of a gethostbyname() call to a socket.

My code currently looks like this:

```
const hostent* host = GetHost(); //This works correctly
    if (!host) {
        DebugMessage("Bad host", "Could not resolve host");
        return NULL;
    }
    DebugMessage("Got host", host->h_name);

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //This funky cast is what i'm concerned about
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = (*((in_addr*)(host->h_addr_list[0]))).s_addr;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);

    DebugMessage("addr", (*((in_addr*)(host->h_addr_list[0]))).s_addr);

    int c = connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    int le = WSAGetLastError();
    if (c == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        //etc...
```

It does work, but It seems to me that that funky cast for assigning the s_addr seems too complex for what I'm actually doing, leading me to beleive that this is not the way it "should be done". Am I just too used to high level languages, and this is the way it's supposed to be, or am I missing a utility function somewhere?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you should use `h_addrtype` rather than assume `AF_INET` and then interpret `h_addr_list` based on that type.  Once you are already assuming `AF_INET` (both in the `socket` and in `connect`) you may as well assume that `h_addr_list[0]` is an `in_addr` as you are doing.  You could check `h_addrtype` in case you got an AAAA record (IPv6) so you can reject it rather than mis-cast it.

Comment: So if I assume `h_addrtype` is definately `AF_INET`, the code I posted is basically correct? That is, this is how I should continue doing it? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the latest and recommended way to resolve domain name is to use `getaddrinfo` ([windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo)).

As far as I know, there is no standard way of making a lookup asynchronously, therefore it's quite common to spawn a thread dedicated to doing DNS lookups.

Comment: My usual favourite is to use `libasyncns`, which creates a sidecar thread or process, communicating via a pipe or socketpair to the main loop. It's easy to add this filehandle to a select/poll/etc.. loop and handle it in a nonblocking way.
http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libasyncns/